# Coining a word for "to make hill-shaped"

Tags: neologism

What would be a good way to coin an English word for "to make hill-shaped", so it conforms to our traditions for drawing upon classical roots?

One possibility is "collify", with "collification" for the noun, from an imaginary Latin word *collificare.* I don't think "collify" suggests its meaning, though. Does the Latin word **collis** appear in any English words?

Another possibility is to draw upon **tumulus**, which echoes in English "tumescence" and "tumor". There is also an English word ["tumulus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumulus), meaning a burial mound. Hmm, tumuli have [exactly the shape](https://www.google.com/search?q=tumuli&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim9-eouaTTAhXJ64MKHZfDBS8Q_AUICCgB&biw=899&bih=708) I want to suggest. How, in Latin, would one make a verb for "to make tumulus-like"?

The intended context for this word is to describe modification of fitness landscapes in genetic/evolutionary algorithms to make them smoother and thus (mathematically, heuristically) easier to "climb". Fitness landscapes that are very un-hill-shaped are commonly called "rough", so another possible Latin root to draw upon is **lēvis**.

If no Latin root works, I may have to go with Greek or else the ugly hybrid "hillify".

---

### Update

The paper with the neologism has been published! Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Kovitz, B., Bender, D., & Poffald, M. (2019, July). [Acclivation of Virtual Fitness Landscapes](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1162/isal_a_00190). In *The 2019 Conference on Artificial Life: A Hybrid of the European Conference on Artificial Life (ECAL) and the International Conference on the Synthesis and Simulation of Living Systems (ALIFE)* (pp. 380-387).

Comment: Neither a neologism nor Latin, but the verb [hill](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/86993) has pretty much this meaning (“to form into a hill or heap”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *clivus* or *mons* for "hill".
Especially the second one is easily recognized, and I believe many English speakers would understand the verb "montify" (< *montificare*) in context.

The word *clivus* might not be as easily recognized, but it might still work well and it leads to natural-sounding derivatives in English.
Starting from *clivus* or a corresponding adjective *acclivus*, one can derive *(ac)clivare* which can be rendered in English as "(ac)clivate".
It seems that ["acclivated"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acclivated) already exists and has a similar meaning.

Comment: Say, is there any relation between _clivus_ and _clino_ (suggested at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clivus#Latin)? The latter is echoed in English "inclination" and similar words. If that connection is real, pointing it out to my audience might help "acclivate" activate the "hill-shaped" or "sloping" concept in their minds.

Comment: @BenKovitz I don't know, but that would make an interesting etymological question.

Comment: [Good idea.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/is-there-a-connection-between-clivus-and-clinatus)

Comment: I found a reasonably well-known English cognate: [declivity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/declivity#English). (I'm still not sure what is the difference between a downward slope and an upward slope. But the notion of "slope" is perfect for the concept I'm trying to name.)

Comment: @BenKovitz Perhaps "declivate" or "declinate" could work as well. But since you are not making an uphill or a downhill but a hill that goes both ways (this does not sound entirely sane, does it?), how about just "clivate" without the ac-? Perhaps "montify" would be clearer even if it focuses more on the mountain rather than the slopes at its sides.

Comment: From [a book on agriculture](https://books.google.com/books?id=gwoHAAAAQAAJ&dq=acclivate&pg=PA411#v=onepage&q=acclivate&f=false) written in 1799: "To acclivate: To ridge up; to make acclivous; to raise the soil from level to sloping; so as to shed off superfluous rain water."

Comment: The OED has no "acclivate" but it does have ["acclivous"](https://books.google.com/books?id=gwoHAAAAQAAJ&dq=acclivate&pg=PA411#v=onepage&q=acclivate&f=false). Generally, the "-cliv-" words seem to suggest a steep slope, not a gentle one, which is a mark against them.

Comment: "Clivate" might be good, but "acclivate" and similiar words seem to have pretty decent precedent, whereas I haven't yet seen "clivate". The "ac-" part suggests going higher (uphill), which is exactly the right meaning for search by hill-climbing.

Comment: Another live cognate: ["acclivity"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1108#eid38951290): an upward slope of a hill.

Answer (score 5):

Though this may not entirely appropriate, the first thing that came to my mind was the Vulgate's rendering of Isaiah 40:4,

> omnis vallis exaltabitur et omnis mons et collis humiliabitur et erunt prava in directa et aspera in vias planas.

The KJV version (as used by Händel) translates as:

> Every valley shall be exalted, and every mountain and hill shall be made low: and the crooked shall be made straight, and the rough places plain.

These words mostly refer to *removing* height differences, not softening them. Here are some other possible words. I have included an English dictionary link and definition where available:

- [*lenify / lenification*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lenify): alleviate, assuage, mitigate, soften
- [*levigate / levigation*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/levigation): to rub, grind, or reduce to a fine powder, as in a mortar, with or without the addition of a liquid. (From Latin *levigo / levigatio*: "to make smooth, to smooth")

**However**, unless I'm really misunderstanding your use case, I think such a neologism would be pointless, since we already have from statistics the concept of data set [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing).

Comment: A reference to a famous Biblical passage would be a great way to explain a neologism at a scientific conference on evolution! And thanks for ''lenify'' and ''levigate'': possibilities with already existing English usage.

Comment: Re your last paragraph: I want to avoid bringing to mind smoothing a data set, since that's approximation, a subtly different idea. In [this topic](http://bit.ly/2ozn781), ["hill-shaped"](http://bit.ly/2ov2lFc) has a very salient meaning: you'll find the peak by always crawling in the direction that locally appears "up". The concept I have in mind is imposing a new topology onto a rough landscape, sort of like corrective lenses, so it "looks" more hill-shaped—_is_ more hill-shaped for purposes of climbing it. IOW, not pretending data is smooth, but finding smooth paths through rough reality.

Comment: @BenKovitz I hope you are modifying topography, not topology. It sounds to me like you want to exaggerate some features so that the algorithm can see them. // Would something like "montify" or "(ac)clivate" sound good to you?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I suppose one could say that an imposed topology makes the topography more hill-shaped. The idea is not to exaggerate features but to change the paths along which an algorithm searches for the peak—"jumping around" in the original topology but climbing along a smooth path in the imposed topology. "Montify" and "acclivate" both sound good! "Acclivate" is probably better. Post an answer!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta "Acclivate" appears to have established usage, even! https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acclivated

Comment: @BenKovitz I posted the suggestions as an answer. // What do you exactly mean by topology? I understand that it means introducing a [topological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) difference, which is a very drastic change of data (eg. adding holes or loops in a structure).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta By "topology" I mean the "neighborhoods" in some space: what points are defined as "near" any given point. Indeed imposing a new topology on a fitness landscape is a drastic change. The one I'm proposing creats paths between points that, in the original topology, are inaccessible or hard to reach from one another. It's a bizarre distortion, but the result should "look" like a hill (in, er, many dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

Mark Antony used "arrigare" for "tumesce" in his letter to Octavian.  (As quoted in Suetonius's *Life of Augustus* "An refert, ubi et in qua tu arrigas?"  at the conclusion of Antony's response to Octavian's accusation that he is having an affair with a foreign queen, he defends himself by saying that that woman is his wife and Octavian *cheats* on *his* wife all the time and that doesn't seem to matter.  Yes, the interplay between politics and sexual morality hasn't changed a ton in 2000 years.)

It's an interesting verb, since it's not easy to translate into English with a single word (though "tumesce" would work literally).  So maybe it could be the basis for coining an English word, though admittedly I initially misread the question, assuming that the asker was looking for a Latin word.  Although as I think about it, maybe it's not even that good a lead since what makes it difficult to translate is that it's intransitive.  English already has a cognate transitive verb, which is what the asker is looking for.  But, if you need to coin an intransitive one, maybe look here for a loan word.

Comment: Interesting word. Could you elaborate on your suggestion a bit?