# Is there a connection between clivus and clinatus?

Tags: etymology

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clivus#Latin) suggests that **clivus** is related to **clino** and **clinatus**. But it doesn't explain the connection. Is there some way that **n** in a verb becomes **v** in a related noun or adjective?

Wiktionary traces both words to the same PIE root, [ḱley-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%E1%B8%B1ley-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*clino* is an example of what Weiss calls **"nasal presents"** (p. 406). In other words (very non-technically), the present form of some verbs has an infix -n-. *vinco* is another good example of this phenomenon.

v in *clivus*, on the other hand, is what happens to *u (in *uo) between vowels. There was a discussion about it here the other day ([vacuus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4681/118)).

Comment: I just added a link for "vacuus". Will you please check that it goes to the correct question?