# Etymology of "ingeniōsus" and "ingenuus"

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, adjective, derivation

Can someone please explain how these two words,

- *ingenuus*
- *ingeniōsus*

both deriving from *gignō*, come to mean what they respectively do?

### BACKGROUND

According to Wiktionary, *[ingenuus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingenuus)* is made of *in-* +‎ *gignō* +‎ *-uus*.

The entry for *[ingeniōsus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingeniosus)* gives no etymology.  So I had to look up *[ingenious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingenious)*, whose etymology is also *in-* + *gignere*; and *[ingenium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingenium)*, again *in-* + *gignere*.

I found *[-ōsus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-osus)*.  I believe this may be the third element in *ingeniōsus*.

My random guess is something like:

- The *in-* in *ingenuus* is a negation.  So the word has the structure of *in-* +‎ [*gignō* +‎ *-uus*], or *not caused*, amenable to meanings like *natural* and *candid* (or *unaffected*).
- The *in-* in *ingeniōsus* means *in* or *at*. So the word has [*in-* + *gignere*] + *-ōsus*, or *[at birth]-full*, amenable to *full of quality* and therefore *clever*.

The answer I am looking for would take each of the words (*ingenuus* and *ingeniōsus*), break it to its constituent parts, identify those parts by meaning and usage, say what was the probable first application of the word, and if possible trace how that might have expanded to the more figurative senses.

For *[-uus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-uus)*, Wiktionary lists *contiguus*, *succiduus*, and *vacuus*.  For these words the present and the perfect stems (maybe these are not the right terms) look alike. But the case of *gignō* perhaps suggests that *-uus* is always attaching itself to the perfect stem?  What happens to other verbs with different present and perfect stems when they take *-uus*? Thank you.

Comment: The linked Wiki clearly says "Usage notes: Affixed primarily to verbs. **Not to be confused with in- (“not”).**"